# Java : How to prevent unexpected token exception from terminating the runtime?

Tags: java, file-io, exception, antlr, lex

I want to scan an input file(.txt) based on a lexer grammar ,and recognize its tokens. but as soon as seeing the first unexpected token,the program terminates and just shoes the first exception.

what should I do to make the program continue and to find and print all the other unexpected tokens up to the end of file.
fore example my input is `int $de #de` but after reaching `$de` the program terminates and doesn't show any exception about `#de`

here is my code :

```
public class Main {

    private static HashMap<String, String> keywords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static HashMap<Integer, String> tokenType = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        setHashMap();
        String type , tokInformation;
        int blkNo=0 , blkOrd =0;

        Token token=Token.badToken;
        FileReader r;
        BufferedReader br=null;
        MyLexer lex = null;

        try
        {
            r = new FileReader("inputFile.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(r);
            lex =  new MyLexer(r);
        }
        catch(IOException u ){ 
            u.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{

            token = lex.nextToken();

            while (token.getType()!= Token.EOF_TYPE)
            {
                if(token.getType()==MyLexerTokenTypes.OPEN_ACCOLADE){
                    blkNo ++;
                    blkOrd++;
                }
                if(token.getType()==MyLexerTokenTypes.CLOSE_ACCOLADE)
                    blkNo--;

                if(token.getType()==MyLexerTokenTypes.IDENTIFIER)
                {
                    type=keywords.get(token.getText());
                    if(type==null)
                        type = "IDENTIFIER";
                }
                else
                    type = tokenType.get(token.getType());

                tokInformation = token.getText() + "\t\t"+ type + "\t\t\t"+
                            token.getLine() + "\t\t"+ token.getColumn()+"\t\t"
                            +blkNo+"\t\t"+blkOrd;
                System.out.println(tokInformation);
                token = lex.nextToken();
            }

        }//end try

        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception: "+t.toString());
            for(StackTraceElement e : t.getStackTrace())
                System.err.println("\t"+ e);
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Are you still using ANTLR v2.7?

Comment: yeah...unfortunately cause video tutorials of ANTLR v3 were blocked in my place, I was forced to use this version and its available documentations :(

Comment: Like I said before: v2 is really, *really* old: don't use tutorials based on v2 to learn ANTLR. There are decent v3 tutorials out there (see my profile for a link to my ANTLR tutorial).

Comment: I just noticed who you are :) thanks for your attention ... believe it or not, even your blog is blocked for me !! I tried it at the first time you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can put the try-catch inside the while loop. Currently exception is handled outside the while loop so while loop is terminated as soon as exception occurs.

Also you don't need to iterate over the StackTraceElement you can instead do `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: I did what you said.but it ended to an infinite loop, just repeating the first exception.

Comment: I think you should modify your lex.nextToken() method to return EOF type if scanner.hasNext() is false. Also share the exception trace for better suggestions.